# Add to array of sub documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering if there is a way in Mongoose to do a bulk update to a child collection in all documents at the same time by adding to the existing child collection.

I have the following document structure:

```
{
 name:'',
 type:'',
 children:[]
}

//the documents have existing children.
myDocumentModel.update({},{children:newChildren}, { multi: true }).exec();
```

The above code is not exactly what I want. It does update all documents, but it overwrites the children instead of adding new children to existing ones. 
Is there a clue I can give to Mongoose to make the update additive and not replace the original children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operator with the [`$each`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier to add an array of elements to an array field:

```js
myDocumentModel.update({},
    { $push: { children: { $each: newChildren } } },
    { multi: true }
).exec();
```